# Python 3 | Using Multiple if statements inside a for loop?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have searched and found nothing that suits my needs.

I have three `for` loops that each has an `if` conditions inside it. Here is the code:

```
for friend in friends:
    columns = friend.split("\n")
    if len(columns) == 4:
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO `fb_friends`(`name`, `no_of_mutual_friends`, `no_of_new_posts`, `already_friends`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)""", (columns))

for friend in friends:
    columns = friend.split("\n")
    if len(columns) == 3:
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO `fb_friends`(`name`, `no_of_mutual_friends`, `already_friends`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)""", (columns))

for friend in friends:
    columns = friend.split("\n")
    if len(columns) == 2:
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO `fb_friends`(`name`, `no_of_mutual_friends`, `already_friends`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)""", (columns))
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I was thinking of the `and` operator like so:

```
 for friend in friends:
    columns = friend.split("\n")
    if len(columns) == 4:
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO `fb_friends`(`name`, `no_of_mutual_friends`, `no_of_new_posts`, `already_friends`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)""", (columns))
and
        if len(columns) == 3:
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO `fb_friends`(`name`, `no_of_mutual_friends`, `already_friends`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)""", (columns))
and
        if len(columns) == 2:
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO `fb_friends`(`name`, `already_friends`) VALUES (?, ?)""", (columns))
```

Can any one suggest the best or most efficient way of doing this as apposed to iterating three times over the same list?

Comment: You could avoid  if statements and  pad `columns` to size 4 instead: `columns + [None]*(4-len(columns))`

Comment: I find your use of `(columns)` **extremely** misleading. It does nothing (you can replace `(columns)` with `columns` and nothing will change), but it is similar to `(columns, )` (note the final comma!) which create a 1-element tuple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full code here:

```
for friend in friends:
    columns = friend.split("\n")
    if len(columns) == 4:
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO `fb_friends`(`name`, `no_of_mutual_friends`, `no_of_new_posts`, `already_friends`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)""", (columns))
    elif len(columns) == 3:
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO `fb_friends`(`name`, `no_of_mutual_friends`, `already_friends`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)""", (columns))
    elif len(columns) == 2:
        c.execute("""INSERT INTO `fb_friends`(`name`, `already_friends`) VALUES (?, ?)""", (columns))
```

Comment: Thanks MaRZoCHi exactly what I needed. I chose your answer as the correct one as it uses my original code in its example

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `if/elif/else`:

```
if len(smth) == 5:
    # do this
elif len(smth) == 6:
    # do that
else:
    # do something else
```

Comment: Thanks ForceBru exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

On top of ForceBru answer which is the cleanest one... here is an alternative one for fun.

```
d = {2: """INSERT INTO `fb_friends`(`name`, `no_of_mutual_friends`, `already_friends`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)""",
     3: """INSERT INTO `fb_friends`(`name`, `no_of_mutual_friends`, `already_friends`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)""",
     4: """INSERT INTO `fb_friends`(`name`, `no_of_mutual_friends`, `no_of_new_posts`, `already_friends`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"""}
for friend in friends:
    columns = friend.split("\n")
    try:
        c.execute(d[len(columns)], (columns))
    except KeyError:
        print("you sure about this columns length which was:", len(columns))
```

Comment: Just to point out that ForceBru and MaRZoCHi answers are basically the same with the exception that MaRZoCHi was more specific to my code, e.g. ForceBru used the numbers 5 & 6 which will never be a length of any of the columns.. and your error handler is a cool addition but is not needed if the code does not allow for any errors :/ but +1 for the use of a `dict`

Comment: Marzochi's answer was not there when I posted :) so wasn't comparing their answers to each other but Forcebru's to mine :). And thanks, if you don't need protection of try/except you can always remove it :).

Answer (score 1):

```
reqtemplate = "INSERT INTO `fb_friends`(%s) VALUES (%s)"
fields = ['`name`', '`no_of_mutual_friends`', '`no_of_new_posts`', '`already_friends`']
for friend in friends:
    columns = friend.split("\n")
    lenc = len(columns)
    c.execute(reqtemplate % (",".join(fields[:lenc]), ",".join("?" * lenc)), (columns))
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand this code, but if I'm correct in my logic the final line here will cause the length of `fields` to be equal length to `lenc`? but I needed to cut out  '`no_of_mutual_friends`' & '`no_of_new_posts`' not  '`no_of_new_posts`' & '`already_friends`' when `len(columns) == 2`. I always have name and already_friends, but don't always have the others

Comment: sofields[:lenc]

Comment: so fields[:lenc] do this
fields[:2] is from 0 included to 2 excluded: '`name`', '`no_of_mutual_friends`'
If you always have '`name`' and '`already_friends`' you have to change the order in fields list

Comment: if already friends is always in the end, you can use other construction:
fields[ : lenc-1] + fields[-1:]